# How to set position of UIView to be the same as a button

Tags: swift, xcode, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIView same size as a button, I need to transform it to be on top of the button. How can i do it using CGAffineTransform ?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
}
```

I know I can get a view's position using `view.frame.origin.x` and `view.frame.origin.y` and I tried getting the button's origin in a similar manner, but it was not allowed.

If I could get the x and y coordinates, is there a way to use `CGAffineTransform` to transform a view to the desired position?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(x: myButtonX, y: myButtonY)
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is. First, a `UIButton` is technically a subclass of a `UIView`. Second, what do you mean by "possession"? (This could be a language issue.) Finally, could you post enough detail - both code and question - to help someone duplicate what you are seeing? For now it "feels to me" like you are either having an animation issue or a view hierarchy issue.

Comment: My apologies, I updated the topic, it should be "position". Basically I need the `hhview` to move ontop of the button.

Comment: I understand, typos are my biggest issue. :-) So a few followup questions. You state that getting the button's origin isn't allowed. Why? What was the error? Second, are you trying to move a `UIView` over a `UIButton` but yet keep the functionality of tapping the button? Finally, are you using IB and/or auto layout?

Comment: Adding this as a second comment because I'm hoping that will work best. The *key* piece is how you are using the `UIView` and `UIViewController` lifecycles. It *should* be an easy thing to move a view over another - but it depends on a couple of things like auto layout constraints and where they are defined, and what overrides you are trying to do. I use `UIView.animate` instead of `UISplitViewController` and it's (poorly called IMHO) primary VC to have a "slide out" VC. So with a bit more detail, I may be able to help.